# Many hosts in jdbc connection to teradata

Tags: java, jdbc, teradata

We are using jdbc url like:

```
jdbc:teradata://10.77.59.100/DATABASE=MY_DB, CHARSET=UTF8
```

Now I have problem with jdbc connection since our teradata database works in cluster mode.
I try to write:

```
jdbc:teradata://10.77.59.100,10.77.59.101/DATABASE=MY_DB, CHARSET=UTF8
```

But it doesn't work.

Is it possible to set the second teradata server in jdbc url, how it works in MySQL? for example:

```
jdbc:mysql://192.168.29.20:3306,192.168.29.20:6306/mysql
```

Thanks!

Comment: i don't know anything about teradata but `10.77.59.100,10.77.59.100` looks like you are specifying the same server twice probably communication over a default port. For me it seems the server hasn't any chance to tell that it should work as two instances. JDBC Urls are database specific. It should be in  the docs somewhere.

Comment: thank you, I fix the same ip's in the question. They are different. Documentation for teradata give me only one example where jdbc url have one server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when Teradata environments are configured with more than a single node the IP addresses are mapped to multiple COP entries in DNS. You can then provide your JDBC connection the hostname without the COP suffix and it will randomly select a COP entry to attempt to connect. If the first COP entry does not succeed it will try another.

`jdbc:teradata://DatabaseServerName/database=MY_DB,CHARSET=UTF8`

COP Discovery will then try `DatabaseServerNameCOP1` then `DatabaseServerNameCOP2` until it exhausts available COP entries or times out.

The COP discovery feature can be disabled as a parameter in your connection string: `COP=OFF`. Then JDBC will only attempt to use the specified hostname.

Answer (score 1):

I publish a final solution for this question.
I added to the **hosts file** IP addresses mapped to multiple COP entries.

```
10.77.51.100 intd1 intd1cop1 intdcop1
10.77.51.101 intd2 intd2cop1 intdcop2    
10.77.51.102 intd3 intd3cop1 intdcop3    
10.77.51.103 intd4 intd4cop1 intdcop4
```

Then I set JDBC connection string. Teradata host name without the COP suffix.

```
jdbc:teradata://intd/database=MY_DB,CHARSET=UTF8
```

Now, in case of unavailability of one of the nodes, we will automatically switch to another node chosen randomly.